# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)

Tags: android

I Encountered an error No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1). I'm trying search by google but nothing:

FragmentComment.java

```
private void createNew() {
    subscriptions.add(leaderSubscription);
    commentDTO.setType(Constants.TRAINING_DAY_OLD);
    Observable<ResultResponse> observable = candidateRequest.postResultCandidate(commentDTO);
    leaderSubscription = observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new JvSubscriber<ResultResponse>(activity) {
                @Override
                public void handleSuccess(ResultResponse baseResponse) {
                    if (Constants.SUCCESS.equals(baseResponse.getSuccess())) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TrainingActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                        setEnableConfirm();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.success), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        btnConfirm.setText(R.string.title_enable);
                        btnConfirm.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button_history);
                        btnConfirm.setEnabled(true);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),baseResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "JV-SUCCESS: ");

                }

            });
    subscriptions.add(leaderSubscription);
```

CandidateRequest.java

```
public interface CandidateRequest {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST(Constants.URL_RESULT_CANDIDATE)
    Observable<ResultResponse> postResultCandidate(
            @Body CommentDTO commentDTO);

    @GET(Constants.URL_STAFF_SCHEDULE_LIST)
    Observable<StaffResponse> getSchedulesByStaffId(
            @Path("id") long maidId,
            @Path("fromDate") long fromDate,
            @Path("toDate") long toDate);

    @GET(Constants.URL_LEADER_NAME)
    Observable<CandidateLeaderResponse> getLeaderName();
}
```

file `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'


android {
  

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.7.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    ext.googlePlayVersion = "9.6.1"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue

You're using Retrofit 1 annotations with Retrofit 2 or vice versa. Versions 1 and 2 can be used side by side. That doesn't mean their annotations are compatible with the other versions.

#### Cause

Your `dependencies` block is a mess.

#### Solution

Remove Retrofit 1. Only use Retrofit 2 in your own new code. Fix your import statements, import Retrofit annotations from `retrofit2.*` package.

#### More advice

Remove OkHttp 2 and explicitly add OkHttp 3 (Retrofit 2 already adds OkHttp 3.0 implicitly, that's not good enough). Only use OkHttp 3 in your own new code.

Do NOT use different versions of different support libraries. Use the same approach as you did with Google Play services. Extract version string to a variable and use that. You also specified appcompat-v7 twice. If you don't follow this particular advice, you WILL end up with runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the retrofit in your app gradle dependencies.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

like this

Comment: This is build.gradle file

Comment: yes, you need to write this in the dependencies over there.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you Constants.URL_STAFF_SCHEDULE_LIST contains the list of parameters you declared on getSchedulesByStaffId. Probably you're missing the {id} placeholder.

Maybe is a good idea to also paste your URL constants so we can provide better help

Comment: no, I mentioned :

@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST(Constants.URL_RESULT_CANDIDATE)
    Observable<ResultResponse> postResultCandidate(
            @Body CommentDTO commentDTO);

and 
 URL_RESULT_CANDIDATE= "/monitor/training/updateresult";